# Why does the difference happen between the dictionary and the usage?

Tags: usage, definition

> high adjective (ABOVE AVERAGE)
>
> B1
> greater than the usual level or amount:

According to the dictionary, high water should mean lots of water, but why is it wrong in usage?

But high-tar means lots of tar and high protein means lots of protein, is there a rule or something?

Comment: It's because people put words together to make expressions, the meaning of which is different from the meaning of the individual words. It happens in all languages, not just in English. Also, meanings change over time. **Heavy handed** doesn't mean that hands weigh a lot, nor does **light fingered** mean they weigh a little.

Comment: _High water_ isn't 'wrong', it just has the specific meaning of 'high tide'. (another definition of _high_).

Comment: Regarding your title question, the moment the dictionary is "finished" it begins to be out of date. People use language naturally, and a natural part of that process is to use words in new ways.

Comment: Dictionaries in English work the same way as dictionaries in your native language. Why do you say things in your native language that aren't in the dictionary? :)

Comment: Regarding "see": I suppose that most dictionary editors assume you will understand that "perceive with the eyes" means "perceive with the visual apparatus that is unique to the eyes." It is a reasonable assumption.

Comment: @Jeffrey Carney That’s I was meant to say, why do dictionaries leave readers guessing? Why do dictionaries exist? They have to be absolute.

Comment: I've removed the second question, about the use of the word "see".  That was a separate and you should only ask one question per posting.  If you want to ask that question too, please ask it in a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the world of idioms.

"High water" is an idiom. That is, its meaning can't be fully understood from the meanings of the component words. Dictionaries may have separate entries for idioms: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/high-water

Dictionaries are guide. They don't, they can't, cover every shade of usage by every person that has ever used a word.

People who try to get computers to speak in natural languages have this problem: computers have to follow rules, they don't have any common sense.  Dictionaries are not read by computers,  they are read by people, and people are intelligent.  You need to understand that "high" has different meanings in different contexts. So "High mountain" means it is tall. "High tar" means the tobacco releases lots of tar when burned. "High water" is the time when the sea level is at its greatest during the daily tide.

Answer (score 1):

As Kate and Ronald pointed out, "high water" is an expression meaning "high tide".

High can also mean tall, of height. This is the meaning closer for this example.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/high):

> having a specified height or elevation

or, as you listed:

> rising or extending upward a great distance : taller than average, usual, or expected

Comment: High water can refer to a flood as well as a tide.

Answer (score 0):

If you look something up in a dictionary, you need to read what it says. All of it. Carefully.

Look at the definition that you quoted:

> high adjective (ABOVE AVERAGE)
> B1
> greater than the usual **level** or amount

You then say "high water should mean lots of water": the definition does mention amount, but it also mentions **level**. So, according to the definition, high water can mean that the level of the water is greater than usual... and that's exactly what "high water" does mean. When the tide comes in, the water level goes up, and the level of water is greater than usual.